# Sending JSONArray to RetroFIt in Android

Tags: android, server, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for server calls. I need to send a JSONArray to the server. My JSONArray looks like -

```
[{"callName”:”xxx”},{“inputData":{"deviceImei”:”xxxx”,”appVersionUser”:”x”,”osVersion”:”x”,”osType”:”x”,”deviceToken”:”xxxx”}}]
```

I am using RetroFit version 1.9.0 . I tried to use `@BODY`. But I am getting this error -

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: APIClass.GetClientAuthentication: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding"
```

My Api function declaration is,

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/XYZ")
void GetClientAuthentication(@Body JSONArray jArray,
                             Callback<AuthenticationCallBack> aPOJOCallback);
```

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it need to be a `@FormUrlEncoded?` If not, you can make it a @Post only and send the `@Body` property

Comment: I gotta wonder if the curly quotes in the JSON are really supposed to be there.

Comment: @jyanks My base URL is "http://xx.xx.in/xxxx" what should i pass in @POST(""); Earlier i use Volley lib , where above base url is called with the JSONArray filled with input values. Now we are using RetroFit.

Comment: Hi , i got solution ArrayList<AuthenticationErrorJsonResponse> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(authenticationJsonResponse.toString(),
                                new TypeToken<List<AuthenticationErrorJsonResponse>>(){}.getType());

Answer (score 0):

Hey i solved it finally

At the receiving part i took response in JSONElement and converted it to POJO class like below. AuthenticationErrorJsonResponse.java is my POJO class.

```
ArrayList<AuthenticationErrorJsonResponse> yourArray = new Gson().fromJson(authenticationJsonResponse.toString(),
                                new TypeToken<List<AuthenticationErrorJsonResponse>>(){}.getType());
```